# RedirectUrls Being Called, onAuthorize Function Ignored

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal

According to the [documentation on PayPal's Developer site](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-integration/#set-up-the-payment) under Advanced server integration, redirect URLs must be provided in a payment call but:

> (…) PayPal does not automatically call these URLs. PayPal invokes your onAuthorize function when the buyer authorizes the payment.
>    that are provided will not be used.

So I developed my code assuming this to be true, and on my local setup this works fine. But when I push it to my staging server, the redirect URLs being passed in the SDK are being called, and my `onAuthorize` function ignored. It's even opening a new popup window and then opening my `payment-execute.php` script there, with appended `GET` queries, ignoring my `POST`ed values.

Here's a sample of the JS I'm using:

```
paypal.Button.render({

    env: 'sandbox',

    payment: function(resolve, reject) {

        paypal.request.post(
            '/path-to-inc/payment.php',
            {
                action: 'create_paypal_payment',
                orderId: order_id,
                postId: post_id,
            }
        )
        .then(function(data) {
            resolve(data.paymentID);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            reject(err);
        });
    },

    onAuthorize: function(data) {

        paypal.request.post('/path-to-inc/payment-execute.php',
            {
                paymentID: data.paymentID,
                payerID: data.payerID,
                postId: post_id
            })

            .then(function(data) {
                window.location.reload();
            })

            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log('Error');
        });
    }

}, '#paypal-button');
```

And a snippet from the PHP file:

```
$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl('http://website.com/payment-execute.php')
    ->setCancelUrl('http://website.com/checkout');

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale')
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
    ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

try {

    $payment->create($apiContext);

    echo json_encode( ['paymentID' => $payment->id] );

} catch (Exception $e) {

    error_log( 'Payment error: ' . $e->getMessage() );
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but there's a *404* error shown only on the staging server for the following: `https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.4.0.40.js`, though I can see `/checkout.4.0.39.js` is successfully loaded in the network panel of dev tools.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Do you have a demo page I can try which is showing the version error?

Comment: This was in Chrome 55, Safari 10, and Firefox 49, all the same issue. I'll see if I can setup a demo shortly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be happy to take a look

Comment: Found the issue. Please upgrade to v4.0.40. Thanks for finding this!

Comment: Thanks, for the feedback, @bluepnume. Since we were on a short deadline I actually made my own mini-SDK using Guzzle and the cURL documentation on the site. I'll give it another go with the latest `checkout.js` once we have this launch out of the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue since 1 day ago, I was working with onAuthorize call in old tests

Edit 1: Well testing with the old script versions and I get the expected result using this one https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.4.0.38.js

Comment: v4.0.40 has the fix also.

Comment: Now, If I take the file from https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js I'm getting the 4.0.39 version _(which is ignoring the onAuthorize call)_, and when I try with https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.4.0.38.js or https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.4.0.40.js I'm getting a server error